# Call constructor throws 'java.lang.NullPointerException'

Tags: java, enums, constructor, nullpointerexception

I'm building a Blackjack card class using `enum` with constructors.

When I try to call my constructor, I got `java.lang.NullPointerException`.

I have read some threads that says it's about referring to `null` but I still cannot understand why I got this error.

Please see my code below (it compiles, but gives error)

```
public class Card {

    /**
     *  each card should have a suit and a rank
     */

    // Create enumeration for suits, use our abbreviation as the String value

    enum SUIT {
            SPADE ("S"),
            HEART ("H") ,
            CLUB ("C"),
            DIAMOND ("D");

            // need constructor 
            private String abbreviation;

            private SUIT(String abbreviation) {
                this.abbreviation = abbreviation;
            }
    }


    // Create enumeration for ranks with String abbreviation and int value
    enum RANK {
        ACE ("A", 11), // don't worry about the value of ACE = 1 now, we can work on it later
        TWO ("2", 2),
        THREE ("3", 3),
        FOUR ("4", 4),
        FIVE ("5", 5),
        SIX ("6", 6),
        SEVEN ("7", 7),
        EIGHT ("8", 8),
        NINE ("9", 9),
        JACK ("J", 10),
        QUEEN ("Q", 10),
        KING ("K", 10);

        // need constructor 
        private String abbreviation;
        private int value;

        private RANK (String abbreviation, int value) {
            this.abbreviation = abbreviation;
            this.value = value;
        }
    }


    // instance var
    public SUIT suit;
    public RANK rank;

    // Card constructor, each card should have a suit and a rank
    public Card (SUIT suit, RANK rank) {
        this.suit = suit;
        this.rank = rank;
    }

    // method to get the name of the card
    public String name;
    {
        name = this.rank.abbreviation + this.suit.abbreviation;
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        SUIT c = SUIT.CLUB;
        RANK j = RANK.JACK;

        System.out.println(c.abbreviation);
        System.out.println(j.abbreviation);
        System.out.println(j.value);

        Card cd = new Card(c, j);
    }

}
```

Comment: How come 10 isn't in your ranks?

Comment: Good point! Somehow I thought Jack is 10... Thanks for saving me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is that you have an initializer block

```
// method to get the name of the card
public String name;
{
    name = this.rank.abbreviation + this.suit.abbreviation;
}
```

which gets executed when the class Card is instantiated but before the code of the constructor. This means that the fields this.rank and this.suit have not yet been set to any non-null value.

If the comment is correct and you indeed want to define a method rather than an initializer block you would need to re-write it like this:

```
// method to get the name of the card
public String name() {
    return this.rank.abbreviation + this.suit.abbreviation;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, the explanation is very clear and the solution works!